# Passing System.Exception object to WCF Service method as a parameter

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, exception

I need to pass system.exception class instance to the WCF Service method.

If you have any idea about this, please share it.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very dangerous idea, because some exceptions are not serializeable and will cause other exceptions when you try to pass them.

WCF has FaultContracts which are the way to go when handling exceptions. Here is a an example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650899.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass an Exception as a method parameter to a WCF Service I guess your design has a flaw.

Passing an Exception instance as a parameter is definitely not the best way to transmit errors with WCF.

Comment: thanks stuntman. i am new to WCF service.so the design may have several issues. Appreciate your help and definitely I will consider your comment.At the same time it will make more happy, while getting the answer for the asked question.  thanks again stuntman

Comment: Please include more details in your question, otherwise it would be difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: okay stuntman.initially i tried to explain the question fully, but got error while posting, then i posted the question simply.